# SSIS Result Set for each user -> output to email

Tags: ssis

Hello I'm trying to create a Data Flow Task that sends an email out to a list of users. It also needs to send a different body out for each user.

I've got the first part, looping through a select of all users and assigning that to a variable which then uses a for loop container to send an email to each distinct user.)
 I also need it to do the same for the body. However I'm not sure how to do this. As the body contains multiple row sets and not just a single 'user' like the user email query/variable.
**Answer**

I ended up sticking with the send mail task and using for each loop containers to generate and send a file as an email attachment rather than creating my own functions etc.
This was the best and most flexible solution for my needs.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the html body part, you could either try:

1. use`send mail task`, and set the expression for each `recipient` and `message source`
2. Write a Store procedure for modify the html part based on different recipient and send that by `Database mail`, using `EXEC msdb..sp_send_dbmail`

the SP will look like this:

```
DECLARE    @Body NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE    @HTMLHead VARCHAR(1000)
DECLARE    @HTMLTail VARCHAR(1000)
DECLARE    @CurrentDate VARCHAR(1000)
DECLARE    @Subject VARCHAR(500)
DECLARE    @recipients VARCHAR(500)

if (@recipients = ...)
begin
set @body =...
set @body = @HTMLHead +@body + @HTMLTail 

if(--for each recipient you need to iterate)

EXEC msdb..sp_send_dbmail 
        @profile_name   =   'your db profile name',
        @recipients =   @recipients,
        @subject        =  @Subject,
        @body = @Body,
        @body_format    =   'HTML',
        @blind_copy_recipients = @blind_copy_recipients;
```

I would strongly recommend use the 1st method, which is very clearly since you have already figured out the first part, just add few `send mail task` after the one you get for recipient, and set the precedence constraint to `expression` which should be something like `@recipient =="John@email.com"`, then the constrained task is the `send mail task` you need to configure.

for the 2nd one, you have to set and configure the `db mail`profile and account first, you could find that in **Management -> Database Mail**

Comment: let me know if you have any problem when creating this job

Comment: I managed to use the first method but quickly realized it's an issue since I really need to present a full result set in the email and it would be best if it was in html, for formatting purposes. This is where I'm now stuck again. I'll look into method two.

Comment: if you are using the first one, it is kind of easy for pure message contents other wise you have to use html page for generating the body part such as for pulling data from table, format into list and etc.

Comment: hmmm, if I understand correctly I can output my resultset to an HTML file then read that file back in as a bodysource/variable, which will retain all HTML formatting ?

Comment: no, you cannot using any html code as the source of the `send mail task`, that only accepts plain characters, if you would like to format a html page, you need to use `script task` or the 2nd method I post